# 2 multi select boxes dependent of each other, 2nd select text value not updated

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, multi-select

I have 2 multi-select boxes like this

```
<div class="form-group mb-3">

   <p class="mb-1 font-weight-bold text-muted mt-3 mt-md-0">Addons</p>
   <p class="text-muted font-13">Select multiple Addons</p>
   <select class="form-control select2-multiple" id="multi-select-add-ons" data-toggle="select2"
    multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Choose ..." style="width: 100%;">

         <optgroup label="Select addons..">
             @foreach ($addons as $a)

               <option value="{{$a->id}}">{{ $a->name }}</option>
             @endforeach
         </optgroup>


    </select>
    <div class="form-group">
         <input id="resultAddons" type="hidden" name="addons_id">
    </div>
</div>


<div class="form-group mb-3">
 <label for="simpleinput">SubAddons</label>
  <select name="" id="subAddons" class="form-control select2-multiple" data-toggle="select2" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Choose ..." style="width: 100%;">

      <optgroup label="Select subaddons..">
           <option value="0"></option>
      </optgroup>

 </select>
 <div class="form-group">
  <input id="resultSubAddons" type="hidden" name="sub_addons_id">
 </div>
</div>
```

Ok so I am using the following code in Script section to get data from Api

```
<script>
$('select').change(function () {
    var addons = $("#multi-select-add-ons").val();
    //console.log(addons);
    $('#subAddons').find('option').not(':first').remove();

    addons.map(item => getSubAddonsByAddon(item)) //call subaddons by addon id api
    addons = addons.join(", ");

    document.getElementById('resultAddons').value = addons;
    
  });

  function getSubAddonsByAddon(id) {

    let baseUrl = 'http://localhost.test/add-ons/'
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", `${baseUrl}show/${id}/sub-add-ons`, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() { // Call a function when the state changes.
        if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status === 200) {
          let data = JSON.parse(this.response);

          let complexArr = [data][0].data;

          complexArr.forEach(element => {
           // console.log(element.name);

            getSubAddonIdAndName(element);
          });
          
        } 
    }
    xhr.send();

  }
  let subAddonID, name;
  
  function getSubAddonIdAndName(data) {
    
    this.subAddonID = data.id;
    this.name = data.name;

    $("#subAddons").append($('<option>', {
        value: data.id ,
        text: data.name
    })); 

  }
</script>
```

Here's how it looks, the code works fine, the 2nd select (sub-addons) dropdown is updated as per the selection of addons, how the name is not displayed inside the select box text field

[image]

After selecting a value from 2nd select box, the value is not displayed like the first select box value's

[image]

It goes back to "Choose..." instead of displaying name like first box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show option inside select-box textfield you can add  `selected: true` line when you append new option inside your `select2` and then  `$("#subAddons").trigger("change")` to update your select2 plugin .

Then , your second issue is because of `$('select').change(function () {` line as you have use `select` as selector so when you change option inside your second select-box this event gets called and option are getting again updated . So , to avoid this just use more specific selector i.e : `select#multi-select-add-ons`

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$("#multi-select-add-ons ,#subAddons").select2()
//be more specific here
$('select#multi-select-add-ons').change(function() {
  var addons = $("#multi-select-add-ons").val();
  $('#subAddons').find('option:not(:first)').remove();
  addons.map(item => getSubAddonsByAddon(item))
  addons = addons.join(", ");
  document.getElementById('resultAddons').value = addons;

});

function getSubAddonsByAddon(id) {

  /*let baseUrl = 'http://localhost.test/add-ons/'
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", `${baseUrl}show/${id}/sub-add-ons`, true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() { // Call a function when the state changes.
    if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status === 200) {
      let data = JSON.parse(this.response);*/
  //suppose this is data came from server
  let data = [{
    "data": [{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "abc"
    }, {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "ace"
    }]
  }]
  let complexArr = data[0].data;
  complexArr.forEach(element => {
    getSubAddonIdAndName(element);
  });
  $("#subAddons").trigger("change") //after appending options refresh select2

  /*}
  }
  xhr.send();*/

}
let subAddonID, name;

function getSubAddonIdAndName(data) {

  this.subAddonID = data.id;
  this.name = data.name;

  $("#subAddons").append($('<option>', {
    value: data.id,
    text: data.name,
    selected: true //add this
  }));

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>


<div class="form-group mb-3">

  <p class="mb-1 font-weight-bold text-muted mt-3 mt-md-0">Addons</p>
  <p class="text-muted font-13">Select multiple Addons</p>
  <select class="form-control select2-multiple" id="multi-select-add-ons" data-toggle="select2" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Choose ..." style="width: 100%;">

    <optgroup label="Select addons..">


      <option value="1">A</option>
      <option value="2">A2</option>
      <option value="3">A3</option>

    </optgroup>


  </select>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input id="resultAddons" type="hidden" name="addons_id">
  </div>
</div>


<div class="form-group mb-3">
  <label for="simpleinput">SubAddons</label>
  <select name="" id="subAddons" class="form-control select2-multiple" data-toggle="select2" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Choose ..." style="width: 100%;">

    <optgroup label="Select subaddons..">
      <option value="0"></option>
    </optgroup>

  </select>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input id="resultSubAddons" type="hidden" name="sub_addons_id">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yup, I figured this out probably forgot to update here.. Yes, my select change function was updating values twice. Thanks, I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a library for the multiple select, what happens is the library runs a handling method on your inputs for whatever data it has for the first time, if you append more data to it you need to re-call the handle method of that library.

Comment: This is not an answer, it should be a comment. Please read [answer]

Comment: Thank you, but If you read it well you will notice that I can't comment if my reputation is below 50 :)

Comment: The data is already coming mate.. When i select the sub-addons option i dont get the selected value displayed like the first box

Comment: What I'm saying is when you add new data options to the multi-select you need to trigger the change api so it will render the select and take effects
`$('#mySelect2').append(newOption).trigger('change');`